# Unable to generate initial values for node <hyperprior> of type UpdaterGamma.Updater in openbugs

Tags: r, bayesian

I am trying to run the following model in R with OpenBugs

```
model {
    # Likelihood. 
    for ( i in 1 : N ) { 
        Y[i] ~ dnorm( mu[i], tau ) 
        mu[i] <- alpha+beta*x[i]}
    # Prior.
    sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
    alpha ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
    beta ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
    tau ~ dgamma(1.0E-3,1.0E-3)
}

datalist = list(
    x = c( 1,2,3,4,5 ) ,
    Y = c( 1,3,3,3,5) ,
    N = 5
)
```

And it hits the following error:
"model is syntactically correct
data loaded
model compiled
unable to generate initial values for node  of type UpdaterGamma.Updater
Error in samplesSet(c("alpha", "beta", "tau")) : 
  model must be initialized before monitors used"

However, after assigning a value to tau, i.e. tau<-1.0, it can run without error.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: It seems like OpenBUGS is having a hard time generating initial values; have you tried generating those values yourself and passing them to OpenBUGS (for example, by using the `inits` argument in the `bugs` function in the R2OpenBUGS package)?

Comment: I have converted the code to use JAGS and it works. I will find some time to try the inits function in OpenBUGS later. Thx.

Comment: Good to hear. I actually prefer JAGS myself, and there's the option to specify initial conditions with it as well (at least in the `jags.model` function in the `rjags` package, maybe for related packages as well).